# Trying to extract elements from a List<model> and display in Blazor razor component

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I am brand new to Blazor Server, coming from a background in ASP.NET Webforms. I have a database that stores questions and answers for an employee safety test, and Im trying to display the test questions programatically in the HTML section of my page. When debugging, I get an Index Out of Range error.

Related Code:

```
@code {
private List<IForkLiftPerfTestContentModel> testquestion = new List<IForkLiftPerfTestContentModel>();
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    testquestion = await testService.GetTestQuestions();
}
```

When I debug **testquestion**, it displays data properly as shown:

[image: Debug]

When I try to display an element by zero-based index, I get Index out of Range, although Intellisense doesnt complain about my code:

```
<td>
   @testquestion[0].Topic
</td>
```

Clearly Im missing something, but again I am learning Blazor. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the html is rendered before OnInitializedAsync is called or returns, at which point testQuestion is still null. Guard against that and it should work.

Comment: At the same time, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1) suggests that rendering should be postponed until after the OnInitializedAsync task is awaited ...

Comment: Thanks @jeroenh!  That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your blazor page will render first time, it will not yet have awaited your async operation, it will re-render once that operation is done.
Meaning on first render your `testquestion` will be empty - that's why you have Index Out Of Range, so you need to handle it, say for example "if testquestion is empty - display loading"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nikita! That was perfect!

I wrapped the Edit Form in an if/else like this:

```
@if (testquestion.Count == 0)
{
<h4>Test Loading...</h4>
}
else
{ <Editform>.....</EditForm>
```